# How to return physical lock error without waiting in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, locking, sql-update, ibatis

in my project using java, ibatic and MySql.

Before any updating data into database, i lock the table with  `SELECT FOR UPDATE` query

```
eg: SELECT * FROM MEM_MST WHERE MEM_ID = #memId# FOR UPDATE
```

It make locking the table properly. but the problem is, for example if two client are update the table in same time. first one is lock the table and update but second one is waiting to update until a lock is released. After then second one also update the data. So, first one updated data is overwrite. Please see the following explanation:

```
Time |  Client 1           | Client 2  
-------------------------------------------------
1    | SELECT FOR UPDATE   | 
2    | UPDATE              | SELECT FOR UPDATE (Waiting) 
3    | COMMIT              | (Waiting)
4    |                     | UPDATE
5    | (Overwritten)       | COMMIT
```

So, Client 1 updated data is lost

What I want to be is want to simply return the error message to Client 2 instead of waiting until a lock is released.

Please advise me the way to solve above mentioned problem.

---

P.S:

I already set the lock wait timeout to 0 in startup Variables, but it still take about 2 second to tell "Lock wait timeout exceeded" message.

furthermore,`SELECT FOR UPDATE NO WAIT` is not working in MySQL

Comment: If you have control over every locking statement, you could use named locks with e.g. [`IS_USED_LOCK()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_is-used-lock).

Comment: @eggyal thanks for your comment. trying with <code>IS_USED_LOCK()</code> is ok. But it's not really lock neither the table nor database. Moreover i have to carefully release the every lock by<code>RELEASED_LOCK</code> after every locking statement. If i miss to release the lock, it will be locking ever until sever restart.

Comment: This does not really lock the table, but provides a method for synchronisation. There is no native way to do what you are asking for, I believe. As for the drawback you mention, the constraint already exists with your inital approach: the transaction must be ended, or else the row would be locked forever.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, [`innodb_lock_wait_timeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout) can't be set lower than 1.

You will have to implement your own synchronisation mechanism. As an alternative to eggyal's suggestion, you could add a "semaphore" field to your critical table. Basic workflow (pseudo-code):

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT locked FROM MEM_MST WHERE MEM_ID = @id FOR UPDATE;
if (previous_result == 1) {
    ROLLBACK;
    throw new Exception();
}
UPDATE MEM_MST SET locked = 1 WHERE MEM_ID = @id;
COMMIT; -- from now on, concurrent attempts will fail immediately

START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE MEM_MST SET whatever = @some_value WHERE MEM_ID = @id;
UPDATE MEM_MST SET locked = 0 WHERE MEM_ID = @id; -- release lock
COMMIT;
```